# Django query database and send data to template

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, highcharts, django-views

I am still new to Django/web development but have experience with Python and PSQL.

I have a psql database with a table that has an **id, date, and value** for a stock portfolio. The table is titled absolutedollarvalue.

I want to send the data to the template and then graph it using Highcharts.JS. From what I understand, I need to set up models.py to query the database, which is installed in Django, convert it to JSON, and then send this to the template for graphing.

Can anyone tell me if this is the right syntax to get the id, date, and value, and how to send the date and value in json format to the template?

This is the applicable model part:

```
class Absolutedollarvalue(models.Model):
    cik = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    date = models.DateField()
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=65535, decimal_places=65535)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'absolutedollarvalue'
```

Below is my views.py code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import connection
from toa.models import Absolutedollarvalue as adv
import psycopg2
import json
import datetime

def adv(request):
    adv.objects
    a = adv(id = '1103804')

    return render(request,toa/graphs.html,a)
```

This is my template:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title> Fund Performance </title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var absolutedollarval = {
        chart: {
          renderTo: 'chart_panel',
          type: 'time-series',
        },
        legend: {enabled: false},
        title: {text: 'Daily NAV'},
        xAxis: {title:{text:'Date'}},
        yAxis: {title: {text: 'dollar value'}}
      };
      var chartDataUrl = "{% url 'chart_data_json' %}?name = avg_by_day"
        +"&days=14";
      $.getJSON(chartDataUrl,
      function(data){
        absolutedollarval.xAxis.categories=
        absolutedollarval.series[0].name = 
        absolutedollarval.series[0].data = 
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(absolutedollarval);
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Really appreciate any help you can give. Thanks!

Edit:

Is this how you would push the value to the template if I want the date and value column?

```
def adv(request): 
    dates = adv.objects.filter(cik = '1103804').values('date') 
    vals = adv.objects.filter(cik ='1103804').value('absolutedollarvalue') 
    data = serializers.serialize('json', dates) 
    data2 = serializers.serialize('json',vals) 
    return render(request,'toa/graphs.html',{"dates":data,"values":data2})
```

Comment: Your `adv` function looks like nonsense. You should read the django docs to learn how to write a view function and pass variables to be rendered in a template.

Comment: I used the django docs on retrieving  objects and they gave the example: >>> Blog.objects
<django.db.models.manager.Manager object at ...>
>>> b = Blog(name='Foo', tagline='Bar')
>>> b.objects

Comment: So I'm thinking that object a should give me all the rows of data with that id. I just want to convert the date and value to json and then send it to highcharts

Comment: The Django docs do certainly *not* give that as an example of how to query. Please read the tutorial.

Comment: Do `adv.objects.filter(cik = '1103804').values('Column1','Column2') `, You will get the list of dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send value in JSON format to template:

```
from django.core import serializers

def adv(request):
    adv.objects
    a = adv(id = '1103804') #Will fetch all the column
    a = adv(id = '1103804').values('columnName') #Will fetch the particular column.
    data = serializers.serialize('json', a)
    context = Context(data)
    return render(request,'toa/graphs.html',context)
    render(request, "foo.html", {'jsonKey': jsonValue}) #For passing individual JSON
```

Comment: Is there a way to send the data separately? like the date column, and the corresponding value column?

Comment: So that it's easy to have separate data for the x and y-axis in highcharts?

Comment: @user3628240, you can pass it like this `render(request, "foo.html", {'jsonKey': jsonValue})`

Comment: Ok, thanks! Could you tell me how you would get the individual columns for adv? So object a should basically be groups of tuples with the id, date, and value. I want to pass the date and the corresponding value. Do I need to do another query?

Comment: Also, is there a difference between adv.objects.filter(id="1103804") and the way you wrote it above? Thank you for the help

Comment: Query `adv.objects.filter(id="1103804").values('columnName')` will fetch the individual column for all the matching row .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135027/discussion-between-user3628240-and-piyush-s-wanare).

Comment: is this how you would push the value to the template if i want the date and value column?
def adv(request): 
dates = adv.objects.filter(cik = '1103804').values('date') 
vals = adv.objects.filter(cik ='1103804').value('absolutedollarvalue') 
data = serializers.serialize('json', dates) 
data2 = serializers.serialize('json',vals) 

# context = Context(data) 
return render(request,'toa/graphs.html',{"dates":data,"values":data2})